# Python - Selenium Webdriver find an element where all the div nodes have similar names

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, webdriverwait

I am trying to access a div where all divs have the same name. Let me explain. I am just starting out with selenium and python and I am trying to scrape a webpage just to learn. I ran into the following problem. I made the example html to show the buildup of the webpage. All the divs have the exact same class and title. Then there is the h1 tag for the item and the p tag for the color (which is a clickable link). I am trying to search a page when you give it certain instructions. Example: I am looking for a white racebike. I am able to find the bikes with the first line of code, but how do I find the right color within the racebike section? If I run the Python mentioned below I get an error message. Thanks in advance!

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <div class=div title=example>
            <h1>racebike</h1>
            <p class='test'>black</p>
        </div>
        <div class=div title=example>
            <h1>racebike</h1>
            <p class='test'>white</p>
        </div>
        <div class=div title=example>
            <h1>racebike</h1>
            <p class='test'>yellow</p>
        </div>
        <div class=div title=example>
            <h1>citybike</h1>
            <p class='test'>yellow</p>
        </div>
        <div class=div title=example>
            <h1>citybike</h1>
            <p class='test'>green</p>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

```html
test = (self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(), racebike)]"))
test.self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//*[contains(text(), white)]").click
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To locate/`click()` on the *white racebike* element you need to induce *WebDriverWait* for the `element_to_be_clickable()` and you can use either of the following [xpath](/questions/tagged/xpath) based [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//h1[text()='racebike']//following-sibling::p[@class='test' and text()='white']"))).click()
  ```
- Using `XPATH` considering the parent `<div>`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='div' and @title='example']/h1[text()='racebike']//following-sibling::p[@class='test' and text()='white']"))).click()
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Comment: Thanks for your response! I used the code but got this error:
`code`
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "location of script", line 23, in <module> PythonProj(category, item, color, size)
File "location of script", line 16, in __init__ wait = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//h1[text()='Race Bike']//following-sibling::p[text()='Red']"))).click()
File "location of selenium wait.py", line 80, in until
raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:
`code`

Comment: Sorry had problems with my last comment hopefully this one is clearer to read.
`Traceback (most recent call last):
File "location of script", line 23, in <module> PythonProj(category, item, color, size)
File "location of script", line 16, in __init__ wait = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//h1[text()='Race Bike']//following-sibling::p[text()='Red']"))).click()
File "location of selenium wait.py", line 80, in until
raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:
`
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You can use same xpath which you tried in your solution. It might be possible server is taking too long to repond.

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

element = WebDriverWait(page, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//p[contains(@class, 'white')]")))
element.click()
```

**for multiple bikes with whiite color**

```
elements= WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//p[contains(@class, 'white')]")))
for element in elements:
    element.click()
```

Comment: Thanks for your response! I think this would work in the example I gave on this page, but how would this work when there are multiple bikes with a white color? How do you find the right bike in the right color?

Comment: check updated solution for a multiple bikes with whiite color

Comment: When I use this code I get a raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace) error, what is going wrong?

Comment: I have increased wait please check now

Comment: I got the problem fixed, thank you so much, the code was structured in a weird way so that is why it didn't work. I ended up finding the right xpath using the parent and child methods.